# Querying single audit table for reporting

Tags: sql, audit

I have been playing around with the idea of a single audit table for a few tables in my database.  I found the code on this page: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/pop-rivetts-sql-server-faq-no.5-pop-on-the-audit-trail/

I like the idea, but the only that I am a bit puzzled with is how you would query out the information so that it can be shown in a useful manner.

After you make some changes the audit table looks like this:
[image]

Most of the time in order to do history I would just make a copy of table and add a date
modified column to the end then just copy the whole row into the history table, but that creates a lot of copied data and lots of history tables if you have lots of things to audit.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution to this "nightmare" (loved Dave's comment) is use of two auditing tables populated by audit triggers. You can evaluate the [3rd party solution](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/auditing-triggers-in-sql-server-databases/) which creates both triggers and auditing tables via GUI and then examine how it actually works.

*Dislaimer: I work as a Product Support Engineer at ApexSQL*

Answer (score 2):

I must say that I think this model of auditing is a nightmare.  And I think you've stumbled upon why.  It's very, very hard to reproduce the data as it was using this scheme, not the least of the reasons is that you don't have the data type of what's being changed.  And even if you did, you could very well lose precision in the conversion between a string and your native data type.

No, I think your original idea is much better -- just simply cutting the table rows over.  Most of the time, you don't have to worry about the extra space consumed.  Space is cheap compared the tradeoff in usability that you're making by cutting changes over by column.

Also keep in mind that the scheme that the article describes doesn't even save space for very narrow tables!  It actually might be bigger than the row-level auditing one.

Comment: I guess it depends on how you're going to use your audit data.  For example, imagine that you have an employee with 50 related tables.  If a user wants to see everything that changed for an employee since a given date, querying 50 cut over tables would be a nightmare.  However, it would be trivial with a single table.  However, if you need to automatically restore audited data, instead of just reporting on it, I'd agree with you wholeheartedly.